# Занесение данных в массив из формы и их обработка

Tags: c#

Разрабатываю игру `судоку`, мне нужно, чтобы значения из `numericUpDown` попадали в `массив` и после этого обрабатывались.

```
void EasyToolStripMenuItemClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int i;
        int j;
        int k=0;
        int l=30;
        int[,] EasyArray = new int[,] {
            {9,9,0,3,6,1,8,0,2},
            {9,9,6,0,2,0,9,0,0},
            {2,0,3,4,0,9,0,1,0},
            {8,5,2,0,0,6,0,9,0},
            {0,0,0,8,5,2,7,6,3},
            {6,0,7,0,1,4,0,2,8},
            {0,0,9,2,8,3,1,0,0},
            {3,7,0,1,9,0,2,0,6},
            {0,2,8,0,0,0,3,5,9}
        };
                for ( i = 0; i < 9; i++) {      //Вывод матрицы
                    for ( j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
                if(EasyArray[i,j] == 0) {           //Проверка матрицы
                        NumericUpDown numericUpDown = new NumericUpDown();
                        numericUpDown.Maximum = 9;
                        numericUpDown.Location = new Point(k,l);
                        numericUpDown.Size = new Size(30,30);
                        Controls.Add(numericUpDown);
                    k=k+30;
                } else {
                        Label label = new Label();
                        label.Location = new Point(k,l);
                        label.Size = new Size(30,30);
                        label.Text = Convert.ToString(EasyArray[i,j]);
                        Controls.Add(label);
                    k=k+30;
                }
            }
            l=l+30;
            k=0;
        }
```

Если в массиве значение `0`, то выводится `numericUpDown`, иначе, выводится `label` со значением из массива.

Необходимо, чтобы значение именно например из первого `numericUpDown`, менялись в том же месте где он и был создан (в месте именно массива). Чтобы было более понятно, смотрите картинку ниже:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После этого, мне нужно, чтобы данные проверялись, то есть был проход по всему массиву и проверка на совпадение в ряду, столбце, районе и т.д. Проверку я напишу, но как сделать так, чтобы он была в реальном времени, при изменении `numericUpDown`?

Если можете, то напишите примерный алгоритм или готовый код, пожалуйста!
  Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int[,] EasyArray = new int[,] {
        {9,9,0,3,6,1,8,0,2},
        {9,9,6,0,2,0,9,0,0},
        {2,0,3,4,0,9,0,1,0},
        {8,5,2,0,0,6,0,9,0},
        {0,0,0,8,5,2,7,6,3},
        {6,0,7,0,1,4,0,2,8},
        {0,0,9,2,8,3,1,0,0},
        {3,7,0,1,9,0,2,0,6},
        {0,2,8,0,0,0,3,5,9}
};

void EasyToolStripMenuItemClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  ...
  NumericUpDown numericUpDown = new NumericUpDown();
  numericUpDown.Maximum = 9;
  numericUpDown.Location = new Point(k,l);
  numericUpDown.Size = new Size(30,30);

  numericUpDown.ValueChanged += NumericUpDown1_ValueChanged;
  numericUpDown.Tag = new Point(i, j);

  Controls.Add(numericUpDown);
  ...
}

private void NumericUpDown1_ValueChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e) {
  NumericUpDown numericUpDown = (NumericUpDown)sender;
  Point indices = (Point)numericUpDown.Tag;
  EasyArray[indices.X, indices.Y] = Convert.ToInt32(numericUpDown.Value);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное за внимание, но ошибка все еще есть `"System.Drawing.Point.y" недоступен в силу его уровня защиты` и `System.Drawing.Point.x" недоступен в силу его уровня защиты`. Я очень плохо знаю C#, помогите разобраться с этим пожалуйста!

Comment: @АндрейИванов Пардон, заглавные `X` и `Y`.

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное! Все работает! Удачи во всех начинаниях, счастья, здоровья, я Вам искренне благодарен!

Comment: @АндрейИванов Рад, что смог помочь. Уcпехов! Обратите внимание на значок "галочка" слева от ответа.

Comment: Как раз думал о том, как сделать ответ верным. Готово!